# I don't understand why I am getting this undefined error in my code

Tags: qt, qml

I want to put a condition if the condition is true then show the images. But when i run this code i'm getting an error. It shows image is undefined
here is my code sample

```
Row{
  spacing:5
  Component.onCompleted:{
          if( my condition is true ==true)
            {
            image.source="image_path"
            }
  }
Repeater{
   model: 4
 Image {
      id: image
      Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
      fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The `Image` is inside a Repeater, which is basically a different scope, so from the main qml `image` is not known. Moreover, which of the 4 `image` would you like to address? If you show a bit more about your condition, an suited answer can be written

Comment: suppose i have a condition is like if my password=='y' then i have to show the images. if i'm using a single image then it is working fine but inside a repeater it's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing an id inside Repeater does not work, since the Repeater breaks the scope a bit.

But if you turn around the logic it works: you can bind the `source` property inside the delegate to a new property on the main control (which I named `control` here):

```
Row {
    id: control
    spacing:5

    property bool show : false
    
    Repeater{
        model: 4
        Image {
            id: image
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            source: control.show ? "image_path" : ""
        }
    }
}
```